# Why the album photos coming null from Facebook Graph request in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to write a code in iOS to fetch list of Facebook photos from a specific album but from my iOS app , i am not able to retrieve the list of photos from a album id. It return null.

MyCode:

```
FBSDKGraphRequest *request = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc]
                              initWithGraphPath:@"/195146297190415/picture"
                              parameters:@{@"fields": @"url"}
                              HTTPMethod:@"GET"];
[request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
    // Insert your code here
    NSLog(@"fetched Albums Photo:%@", result);

}];
```

So , this is the above iOS code retreive photos from a album id. Please let me know , where i am doing wrong and why list of photos are coming null.

Comment: Do you get email like fields?

Comment: anyway, what´s that user id? is in an app scoped id of an authorized user? is the access token valid?